# How transliterate unicode text with PyICU to ASCII?

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii, icu, pyicu

There is the [PyICU](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU) library, which I understand can be used to transliterate strings. However there are no docs. Anyone have a simple example which transliterates a unicode string to ASCII, with [PyICU](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU)?

The C++ [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) documentation [for transliteration is here](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Transliterator.html), but I don't understand how to call it from Python.

Comment: related: [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks, I actually found that and went for that. But I still thought that this question has some value, so I let it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice cheat sheet for PyICU here: https://gist.github.com/dpk/8325992

Here's a slightly modified example:

```
>>> import icu
>>> tl = icu.Transliterator.createInstance('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII')
>>> tl.transliterate('Ψάπφω')
'Psappho'
```

Answer (score -1):

From the first link that you gave, I am assuming
1) that you have already built PyICU
2) you have made sure that the library is accessible 
(see documentation on your linked page if you don't have the above)

I found this documentation from your link:

> To convert a Python str encoded in a encoding other than utf-8 to an ICU UnicodeString use the UnicodeString(str, encodingName) constructor.

So you need to find the encodingName, I guess yours would be ASCII (you should check to make sure that it is correct, I haven't bothered)

Then I suppose you would do something like this:

```
>>> from icu import UnicodeString
 . 
 .
 . 
>>> string = UnicodeString(strToConvert, ASCII)
```

That is just a quick idea, ymmv. You might want to check the website as it gives more examples and how to do things the "Python way" or the "ICU way".
CHEERS!

Comment: As I said, I just took a guess on that; just scan the docs for what symbol is supposed to be used for ASCII. You might try something like iso-646, or iso-8859, or perhaps even ascii.